# Ionic: same style for android and iOS

Tags: ionic-framework

In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjPRj2Vp74U) Andrew mentions that Ionic builds different element design for each platform. Is it possible to prevent that, so the app looks the same on all platforms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this is 100% possible.

This can be achieved with the Ionic `$ionicConfigProvider`. You can use this provider within your `.config()` method and do things like override which platform specific styles you want to.

Its a pretty powerful tool.  Have a look at the [**docs**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/) for full info.

Answer (score 15):

For **Ionic 2.0.0** you can use the config parameter of the [IonicModule](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/IonicModule/) forRoot method.

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {mode: 'ios'}),
```

Comment: Working in Ionic 4 too! :)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Ionic2...

open `app/app.ts`

and add the next config:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {
  mode: 'ios' // use 'md' for android and 'wp' for windows 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> The ionic.Platform utility can be used in your JavaScript controller
>   to set the platform for your app.

Actually it can set and get the platform, the trick is to run the set command in the run method for your module before everything else is set:

```
angular.module('YourAppName').run(function () {
    //override platform
    ionic.Platform.setPlatform("android");//all styles will be unified on both Android and iOS 


});
```